# How to fix "Bad request" error when sending Rest request to Google Oauth2 SSO in HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, oauth-2.0

I´m trying to learn how to implement Googles Oauth2 SSO login function. So far I´ve gotten to the point where everything works except when I try to send a request to "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" using REST in C# to get the Access_code/Token. I´ve registered my localhost and the corresponding port on google and I´ve managed to get my POST request to work in POSTMAN however when i try sending a request in C# my HttpRequestMessage returns 400 bad request.

First I have an Authorization.aspx page that runs a command that redirects the users to googles authorization page where the user login and then gets redirected to my page http://localhost:64716/GoogleCallBack.aspx which picks up the response. In the page it picks up the authorization code and tries to send a POST request to the base URL. I´ve tried running it in POSTMAN where it works (although only with a new authorization code). So I know it is my C# code that is the problem. I´ve tried using webrequest and I´ve also tried changing the Media type to application/Json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Error = Request.QueryString["error"];

        string Code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (Error != null) { }
        else if (Code != null)
        {

            string UserId = Request.QueryString["state"];
            int Id = Convert.ToInt32(UserId);
            string AccessToken = string.Empty;
            string RefreshToken = ExchangeAuthorizationCode(Id, Code, out AccessToken);
            string Url = "Authorize.aspx?UserId=" + UserId;
            Response.Redirect(Url, true);
        }
    }
    private string ExchangeAuthorizationCode(int userId, string code, out string accessToken)
    {
        string baseurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        accessToken = string.Empty;
        string ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecrete"];
        string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        string RedirectUrl = "http://localhost:64716/GoogleCallBack.aspx";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/Json"));

            var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Code", code));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_id", ClientId));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_secret", ClientSecret));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Redirect_uri", RedirectUrl));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_type", "offline"));

            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };
            var resres = client.SendAsync(req).Result;

            return "temp";

        }

    }
```

I want my response to be statuscode 200 with an access_token from google (Like it does in Postman)

Comment: Ive not seen oauth tokens tried to be sent like this.  Do your headers match the postman ones?

Comment: In this particular example no, in Postman i use application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/json but I have tried adding that too. It did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[resolved] This is what I did (With the help from a few friends)

1. Changed Headers to JSON
2. Moved the Base URI to PostAsync()
3. Once I had change all that I could see that the error was in the redirect_Uri and I then changed it to match the one in postman. And now it works

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //you will get this, when any error will occur while authorization otherwise null    
           string Error = Request.QueryString["error"];
           //authorization code after successful authorization    
           string Code = Request.QueryString["code"];
           if (Error != null) { }
           else if (Code != null)
           {
               //Remember, we have set userid in State    
               string UserId = Request.QueryString["state"];
               //Get AccessToken    
               int Id = Convert.ToInt32(UserId);
               string AccessToken = string.Empty;
               string RefreshToken = ExchangeAuthorizationCode(Id, Code, out AccessToken);
               //saving refresh token in database    
               SaveRefreshToken(Id, RefreshToken);
               //Get Email Id of the authorized user    
               string EmailId = FetchEmailId(AccessToken);
               //Saving Email Id    
               SaveEmailId(UserId, EmailId);
               //Redirect the user to Authorize.aspx with user id    
               string Url = "Authorize.aspx?UserId=" + UserId;
               Response.Redirect(Url, true);
           }
       }

       private string ExchangeAuthorizationCode(int userId, string code, out string accessToken)
       {
           string baseurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
           accessToken = string.Empty;
           string ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecrete"];
           string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
           // //get this value by opening your web app in browser.    
           string RedirectUrl = "http://localhost:64716/GoogleCallback.aspx"; //I changed this to match the one in Postman

           using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {
               //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2"); //I replaced the Uri to "var result = client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", nvc).Result;"
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // I made this JSON
               // I removed this "client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");"

               var nvc = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", RedirectUrl),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_type", "offline")
               });

               var result = client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", nvc).Result;

               var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

               var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Authorization_request_body>(resultContent.ToString());

               return "temp";

               }

           }
   ```